# PixiJS Sprite touch reject audio on Safari

Tags: audio, safari, pixi.js

### Code:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    view: canvasRef.current,
    width: RESOLUTION.width,
    height: RESOLUTION.height - 80,
    resolution: 2,
    antialias: false,
    backgroundColor: 0xefefef,
});

const container = new PIXI.Container();
container.sortableChildren = true;
app.stage.addChild(container);
app.stage.interactive = true;
app.stage.hitArea = app.screen;
app.stage.on('pointerup', onDragEnd);
app.stage.on('pointerupoutside', onDragEnd);

const c32 = PIXI.Sprite.from('images/cards/c32f.png');
c32.interactive = true;
c32.position.set(0, 0);
c32.rotation = QA_CARD[0].rotation;
c32.on('pointerdown', onDragStart, c32);
container.addChild(c32);

function onDragStart() {
    new Audio('1.mp3').play(); 
}
function onDragEnd() {
    new Audio('1.mp3').play();
}
```

The `onDragStart()` audio is playing but the `onDragEnd()` audio is rejected. The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with excalibur. It seems that CANVAS interactions are not counted towards "user interaction required for audio".